# Selenium web spider fails to scrape two table <td> tags in a row using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to scrape grades and classroom sizes for multiple schools and years from an [ASP site](https://www.app.edu.gov.on.ca/eng/cst/classSize2.asp?sch_no=282693) using Python, Selenium and Beautiful Soup. My ultimate goal is then putting that data into a pandas dataframe for csv export.  At this point in my script,

```
cells = rows.find_all('td')
```

I get this error:

```
ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, it seems to be offering me two opposite solutions to the same problem. This is this script I'm running, print() statements seem to suggest everything else is fine, and other solutions on Stack Overflow don't seem to offer any insight. Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

```
all_data = []

s = open("toronto_school_ids.txt", "r")
m = s.read().splitlines()

for i in range (0, len(m)):
    school_id = m[i]

    print ("Beginning the search for all schools in the Toronto District School Board...")

    # ontario class size tracker website
    driver.get("https://www.app.edu.gov.on.ca/eng/cst/classSize2.asp?sch_no=" + school_id)
    print("Got the Ontario website...")

    s = open("years.txt", "r")
    m = s.read().splitlines()

    for i in range (0, len(m)):
        year = m[i]

        # selenium takes over
        dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("schYR"))
        dropdown.select_by_value(year)
        print("Got the year we wanted to search for...")

        # Now we can grab the search button and click it
        search_button = driver.find_element_by_id("frmYearsSubmit")
        search_button.click()
        print("Searching for said year...")

        time.sleep(5)

        # We can feed that into Beautiful Soup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

        print("The name of the school we are searching for is...")
        school_name = soup.find_all('h2')[0].get_text()

        table = soup.find('tbody')
        rows = table.find_all('tr')

        all_data = []

        cells = rows.find_all('td')

        print("Now to get grades and class sizes...")

        for cell in cells:
                grade = cell.find('td', {"style": "border:1px solid #000000; padding-left:3px"}).get_text(strip=True)
                students = cell.find('td', {"style": "border:1px solid #000000;"}).get_text(strip=True)


                all_data.append({'School ID number': school_id, 'School': school_name, 'Year': year, 'Grade': grade, 'Classroom size': students})

                print(grade)
                print(students)
```

Comment: Try using `cells = rows[0].find_all('td')`

Comment: Hey! That does allow for my script to run, but then I'm afraid it only collects the first row of the table.

Comment: It won't. the list only contains one element. The reason we do this, is since `find_all()` returns a `list`, so using `[0]` will extract the data from the `list`

Comment: I'm sorry, I might be misunderstanding, forgive me if I'm missing something: I've run the script and I only get the one line of values. If I understand correctly, what `cells = rows[0].find_all('td') ` does is solely select the first <tr> tag of the table. So when I run the last loop of my script, it'll only collect the cells of that <tr> line.

Comment: for row in rows: cells = row.find_all('td') though this would then be a nested loop so you iterate cells for each row. However, cell.find('td',....) is unlikely to work as you are already at cell level. So, do it at the row level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read in data from a file close it after. You want to navigate back a url after you do the years loop. You can instantly put a table into a csv by looping the tr and td values and writing to the csv file.

```
import csv

idsFile = open("toronto_school_ids.txt", "r")
ids = idsFile.read().splitlines()
idsFile.close()
yearsFile = open("years.txt", "r")
years = yearsFile.read().splitlines()
yearsFile.close()
print ("Beginning the search for all schools in the Toronto District School Board...")
# ontario class size tracker website
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    for i in range (0, len(ids)):
        school_id = ids[i]
        driver.get("https://www.app.edu.gov.on.ca/eng/cst/classSize2.asp?sch_no=" + school_id)
        name=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#right_column > h2"))).text
        print(name)
        for j in range (0, len(years)):
            dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("schYR"))
            dropdown.select_by_value(years[j])
            print("Got the year we wanted to search for...")
            search_button = driver.find_element_by_id("frmYearsSubmit")
            search_button.click()
            print("Searching for said year...")         
            table= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td > table"))) 
            wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
            for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
                wr.writerow([d.text for d in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')])
            time.sleep(5)
        driver.back()
    csvfile.close()
```

Outputs

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQD68.png]

Comment: Hey this is amazing, thank you so much! I really appreciate it! I'm a little new to the writerow() function though so I wanted to ask: the function doesn't accept multiple argumements, but in every line written, I want to include the name of the school and the year for which I'm collecting data. How could I do that?